# JBuilder JSON Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Jbuilder gem.

I'm trying to get an attribute of a point like this:

```
{
"point":[33,11]
}
```

My model are like this

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :x, :y
end
```

I'm trying with this, but was not successfully, it returns the point as a string and I need it as integer.

```
json.point "[#{point.x},#{point.y}]"
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Have you tried point.x.to_i ?

Comment: yes, but still not ok, it returns: "[33,11]" and I need [33,11]

Comment: I see , you can try a method , that accepts point.x and point.y and returns an array [point.x,point.y] (as you know , [] represents array in Ruby).

Comment: it works! I will post the answer thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Qumara's comment, you should call `point.x.to_i` and `point.y.to_i`.

You should also remove the quotes around your array parameter.

The line in question inside your JBuilder block should look like

```
json.point [point.x.to_i,point.y.to_i]
```

Comment: It works! I have added a new method in the Point model to returns an array of the points, that is the same to your answer. Thanks!!